# scroll around a image in groovy?

Tags: swing, groovy, scroll, swingbuilder

IM trying to scroll around a image in groovy but not work

IM using this code and appears a image static

How I could scroll with this code

```
panel(layout: new BorderLayout()) {
    scrollPane(size:[100,100],    
    verticalScrollBarPolicy:JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS) {
        panel(size:[200,100]) {
            label(icon: imageIcon(new URL("file:pokemon.png")))
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solve with this

```
  scrollPane(id:'scroll',preferredSize: [200,200], constraints: context.CENTER) {



    panel(layout: new FlowLayout()) {


        label(icon: imageIcon(new URL('file:///path/pokemon.png')))
    }


      }
```